# Android ListView: vertical line next to scroller

Tags: android, layout, android-listview

I'm looking for a way to make my ListView look like this:

[image: listview with a vertical line]

That is, in addition to custom scroller track and thumb (which can be specified by `android:scrollbarTrackVertical` and `android:scrollbarThumbVertical` attributes), I need a vertical decorative line next to the vertical scroller, which would never fade out.

I tried adding the line into the 9patch drawable specified as `android:scrollbarTrackVertical`, but it seems that the scroller is always positioned in the middle of the drawable (is it?), so it missed its 'track'. Also, the track drawable is repeated horizontally, so finally the scroll was rendered left of the vertical line.

All I know for now, is that I can disable scrollbar fading by setting the ListView `android:fadeScrollbars` attribute to `false`.

No Idea how to make the vertical line to be rendered correctly though.

Answer (score 1):

You could just define a custom row for your listview, and define a thin vertical stripe, as some image or whatever you want, as a background or whatever you want, rightly aligned just before the end, to make sure its before the scrollbar.

This would then give an illusion of a connected, right aligned, vertical line.